# form authentication with javascript only + robots

Tags: php, javascript, forms, authentication

I am working with a form which uses Javascript *only* for fields authentication. I need to introduce spam filter. My question is.

1. Should I introduced Server Side Script to address spam issues (more work)
2. Disable user from submitting form, if JavaScript is disabled?
3. Make a separate form for people who have disabled Javascript (for robots for example)

The issue arised because of spam. As a side question. **How does bots work? Do they just disable JavaScript**. It is kind of lame question.

The way form has been coded is quite unorthodox, which means the code changes for PHP script will be considerable, equivalent to designing a new page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I introduced Server Side Script to address spam issues (more work)

Yes

> Disable user from submitting form, if JavaScript is disabled?

You can't. (You could put some blocks that would make it inconvenient for them to submit it, but you can't control what data people send to your server.)

> Make a separate form for people who have disabled Javascript (for robots for example)

No. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

> How does bots work?

They make HTTP requests and process the responses.

> Do they just disable JavaScript.

They usually run on engines which don't support JavaScript in the first place.

> The way form has been coded is quite unorthodox, which means the code changes for PHP script will be considerable, equivalent to designing a new page.

Sounds like it is in maintenance hell and needs refactoring for the sake of any future changes or debugging that might be needed.

Comment: Right it is equivalent to rewriting the whole page, but it is just registration form and a one time thing to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Most bots work by best-guessing the values to insert in form fields based on their `name` attribute; for example, an *email-esque* value will be inserted in a `<input type="text" name="email"/>`, and an advert for viagra will be inserted in an `<textarea name="body" />`

Whilst preventing users with JavaScript disabled will stop **some** (most?) spam coming through, you also run the risk of preventing your ***real*** users from being able to use your website; do you want to run that risk?

The most common way of preventing spam is to ask the user to complete a CAPTCHA; throw them a hard-to-decipher image and ask them to write in the word. reCaptcha is used by many sites, however I'll only include reCaptcha in forms as a last resort.

One of my more favourite ways of preventing spam is to insert fake, hidden, input fields into the form (`type="hidden`), and give them names such as `email`, `website` etc. Normal users will not enter any values for these fields, because they are hidden, but spam bots *might*.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a captcha however this doesn't improve the user experience.

A trick I like to use is add a field name it something like email then use css to hide it and check server side if the value is still empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My question is more design related, which approach is best. The website is used mainly be company employees.